# Can I get Gmail to find contacts in LDAP?

Tags: gmail, contacts, google-contacts

My company directory is in LDAP, but I use Gmail to read my work mail. Can I get Gmail to offer me company contacts by connecting the LDAP to directory to Gmail somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if you can get Gmail to search in LDAP, but you can import LDAP contacts to Gmail contacts and search it there with help of GCALDaemon.

For more info: http://gcaldaemon.sourceforge.net/usage4.html

But I read at some forum that it has been broken. Don't know if somebody has already fix it  or not... :(

Answer (score 0):

Convince your company to migrate to Google Apps, ties into the LDAP / AD easily at that point.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easyer way! if you go to http://memotoo.com and setup an account you can have your Outlook contacts synced using one of the provided applications to that service. They will then sync their server with Google and you get all of your contacts :)

This service also supports syncing your contacts from Facebook, LinkedIn and most other contact, calander online stores so you have a single point of truth that can sync with your phone, outlook and other services.

I like it as it supports pictures as well and you can [check out how I set it up on my blog](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2010/07/07/the-search-for-a-single-point-of-truth.aspx).